# Meteor - should inserting data from an api go into a method?

Tags: meteor

Real simple and short question here, should I put an API into a method when trying to upload files or keep it on the client side?  And also what is the point of methods, I know it's to keep your app safe, but I am not sure how a user would change break the app.  Also, can you explain when to use methods?

```
readImage(e){
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    const CLOUDINARY_URL = "my_URL";
    const CLOUDIARY_UPLOAD_PRESET = "my_Upload_Preset"
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("file", file);
    formData.append("upload_preset", CLOUDIARY_UPLOAD_PRESET)

    axios({
      url: CLOUDINARY_URL,
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      },
      data: formData
    }).then(function(res){
      console.log(res)
      console.log(res.data.secure_url);
    }).catch(function(err){
      console.log(err);
    })
    console.log(file);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file upload itself needs to happen on the client, but it is good practice to put any processing into a server method. If you do all the processing on the client, it means that you need to enable database access from the client, meaning that a malicious user could modify your database from the browser console.

In the server you should check if the logged in user has permission to do the operation requested. These methods can also be called by entering commands from the console, but you make the attack surface much smaller by reducing the number of operations available.

Comment: Yes, the file upload api is just a part of the actual page where I do all the validations and such.  Thanks